# implementing HIDictionaryWinsowShow function and get error: A Carbon window's attributes couldn't be gotten

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to add Dictionary service into my App, So I implementing HIDictioanryWindowShow(). here is my code

> CFRange range=DCSGetTermRangeInString (NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)string,0);

```
CTFontRef font =CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)string, 0.0, NULL);
CGFloat x= [_window frame].size.width/3;
CGFloat y = [_window frame].size.height/2;
```

> HIDictionaryWindowShow(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, range, font, CGPointMake(x, y), YES, NULL);

and when I run my app, there is error say: A Carbon window's attributes couldn't be gotten.
A Carbon window's features couldn't be gotten. Couldn't get window modality: error=-5600

please help me ! thank you !